# AWS - store table of users' ability

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need some guidance about the best way to store a lot of information for a single user using AWS. 
The problem is that every user after signing up to my website needs to pick abilities from a bank of about 40 abilities (properties that any user can chose) and I need to find a good way to store them per user.

I am currently using Cognito for user table, and the dynamoDB to store user information. 
Theoretically, I can just have a column on my dynamoDB for every ability, and then have '1' if user chose it and '0' if not. But this will lead to about 40 extra columns, and I wanted to know if there is a better way of handling this.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a NoSQL database (Dynamo) but thinking relational (columns for everything).  Why not have a table that has, for example, an optional column for each ability?  It's conceptually similar to the relational but the columns don't have to exist for every user and, if an ability is added, there isn't a table upgrade issue.  Something like:

[image]

That would allow you to read a user and determine which abilities they have.  Yes, you'd still have to loop through all possible abilities for a user but not every user needs to have an explicitly set ability.